# Creating a bitfield with Data.Bits

Tags: haskell

I want to use a bitfield with 32 bits that store the result of the last 32 computations in sequence. E.g. 0110 ... would be fail pass pass fail ... . Ideally the latest result should just be pushed on the bitfield whilst then the oldest result "falls away" on the other side. For example: 0110 where 1 is the newest result should become 1101.

I am struggling with the use of `Data.Bits` and don't know how to initialise / create a bitfield. The errors I get are all somewhat similar to

```
 No instance for (Bits a0) arising from a use of `bitDefault'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Bits Int -- Defined in `Data.Bits'
      instance Bits Integer -- Defined in `Data.Bits'
      instance Bits GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in `Data.Bits'
```

Once I add type signatures GHC tells me back about

```
 Illegal literal in type (use -XDataKinds to enable): 32
```

or similar errors. Sometimes it requests the `Kind *` etc.. I think this is some very basic what I am missing here. How can I create a BitField?

Comment: Can we see the code that triggers this error?

Comment: @Ingo My own code is too innocent. I have placed a version here (based on the LLVM code) that should create BitFields, but it gives the same errors: https://gist.github.com/viloocity/f0dc943d2889936249d3

Comment: Try `(bitDefault 32) :: Integer`

Comment: `Expecting an ordinary type, but found a type of kind Constraint` , I guess this is all because I do not know how to initialise / create a BitField at first. However, I read somewhere the BitFields can only be created w Template Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Word32` from `Data.Word` as a bitmap. It is a type that has `Bits` instance and thus you can use methods of typeclass `Bits` on it:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

type Bitmap32 = Word32
bitmap :: Word32
bitmap = 0   -- initialize with zeros

...
testBit bitmap 10 -- test 10th bit

...
pushNewBit :: Bool -> Bitmap32 -> Bitmap32
pushNewBit b bitmap = (bitmap `shiftL` 1) .|. (if b then 1 else 0)
```

Comment: I assume nothing would hindering me to make bitmap an IORef?

Comment: @JFritsch You're right, but take into account that `IORef`s should be used only when they're really necessary - they make Haskell just a clunky C. Try to do your task in functional way - I promise you'll enjoy this :)

Comment: @JFritsch Moreover, your intention to save results in bitmap is not usual for a functional language (unless you want to write in file/network or interface with C/hardware), I'd use `[Bool]` instead, don't be afraid of lists, they're bread and butter of FP.